# Dúvida sobre como ler uma linha em C (sscanf)

Tags: c

Meu objetivo é ler 2 linhas do usuário, onde cada linha possui um quantidade n >= 0 de números inteiros, separados por espaço. O problema é que, quando n = 0 (que é o caso da linha 2 do código abaixo), o programa reemprime os números lidos na linha anterior, quando o desejado era que NÃO imprimisse nenhum número. Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(){
    char linha[1000];

    for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++){          
        scanf("%[^\n]s", linha);            
        getchar();          
        int numeroLido, numChars;
        int pos = 0;
        
        while (pos < strlen(linha)) {
            sscanf(&linha[pos],"%d %n",&numeroLido,&numChars);
            printf("O numero lido na linha %d: %d\n", i, numeroLido);
            pos += numChars;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf()` não foi escrita para isso. É para ler dados tabulares, como arquivos csv. Se você usar uma máscara com muitos especificadores --- aquelas coisas que começam por `%`e não por `%%`, --- pode ler um certo número deles. Mas é como um vetor: o total de especificadores tem que ser uma constante. E tem o lance dos ponteiros. Veja a seguir.

### Exemplo

```
    const char* mascara = "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d "
    //                      1  2  ..                        12
```

Com essa você pode ler até 12 deles. `sscanf()` vai retornar um número entre 0 e 12 indicando quantos conseguiu ler.

#### Umas linhas de teste

```
    const char* linha[] = 
    {
    "-5 -4 -3 -2 -1",
    "4 3 2 1",
    "3 2 1",
    "2 1",
    "                   1", // #4
    "",
    NULL
    };
```

Considere essas linhas de exemplo. Usando aquela máscara vai ler todos sem problema, mas:

- tem que ter um máximo de elementos definido (12 no exemplo)
- é muito chato porque tem que ter as variáveis todas na lista de argumentos porque `sscanf()` e família não alocam memória
- considere a linha #4: `sscanf()` vai saltar uma quantia qualquer de espaços, `TAB` e `'\n'` tentando satisfazer a entrada, só que não vai te dizer quanto da linha saltou para chegar até o `1`. E assim você não consegue usar por exemplo `1 + numero/10` para avançar o ponteiro na linha: você pode avançar os dígitos do número mas não sabe quantos espaços, `TAB` e `newline` a função leu e ignorou. E ainda tem o problema do sinal porque o número pode ser negativo

#### Um programa pra ler essas linhas

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char* linha[] = 
    {
    "-5 -4 -3 -2 -1",
    "4 3 2 1",
    "3 2 1",
    "2 1",
    "                   1", // #4
    "",
    NULL
    };

    const char* mascara = "\
%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d "; // 12
    int numero = 0;

    for(int i = 0; linha[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("==> \"%s\"\n", linha[i]);
        int res = sscanf(*(linha + i), mascara, &numero, &numero,
                         &numero, &numero, &numero, &numero, &numero,
                         &numero, &numero, &numero, &numero, &numero);
        printf("sscanf() retornou %d\n", res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### saída

```
==> "-5 -4 -3 -2 -1"
sscanf() retornou 5
==> "4 3 2 1"
sscanf() retornou 4
==> "3 2 1"
sscanf() retornou 3
==> "2 1"
sscanf() retornou 2
==> "                   1"
sscanf() retornou 1
==> ""
sscanf() retornou -1
```

Esse programa consome linhas de até 12 números, sem problemas. Mas note que precisa de 12 ponteiros na chamada. Claro que eu usei o mesmo endereço e `sscanf()` não se importa. É apenas para ilustrar o que estou explicando. Se for um número pequeno o máximo de números funciona bem.

Mas se o número for maior que uma meia dúzia melhor tentar outro meio.

### Replicando `scanf()`

Um caminho ingênuo seria replicar `scanf()`, pular whitespace, montar strings e passar para `sscanf()` ou `atoi()` para conseguir o número :)

#### Exemplo

```
void processa_linha(char*);
```

O programa a seguir faz isso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void processa_linha(char*);

int main(void)
{
    char* linha[] = {"-5 -4 -3 -2 -1",
                     "4 3 2 1",
                     "3 2 1",
                     "2 1",
                     "                   1",  // #4
                     "",
                     NULL};

    int numero = 0;
    for (int i = 0; *(linha + i) != NULL; i++)
    {   // processa linha 'linha'
        char* p = *(linha + i);  // o inicio da linha
        printf("==>\tLinha %d: \"%s\"\n", 1 + i, p);
        processa_linha(p);
    }
    return 0;
}

void processa_linha(char* linha)
{
    printf("\tExtraidos: [ ");

    char        fase    = 0;
    long long   len     = 0;
    const char* mascara = "%d";
    int         numero  = 0;
    char*       p       = linha;
    char*       pal     = NULL;
    int         res     = 0;
    char*       st      = NULL;

    while (1)
    {
        switch (fase)
        {
            case 0:
                switch (*p)
                {
                    case 0:
                        // acabou
                        printf(" ]\n");  // termina a linha
                        return;
                        break;
                    case ' ':
                    case '\t':
                    case '\n':
                        break;
                    default:
                        st   = p;  // incio de string
                        fase = 1;
                        break;
                };
                p += 1;
                break;

            case 1:
                switch (*p)
                {
                    case ' ':
                    case '\t':
                    case '\n':
                    case 0:
                        // terminou: monta string
                        len = p - st;
                        pal = (char*)malloc(1 + len);
                        memcpy(pal, st, len);
                        *(pal + len) = 0;  // termina a string
                        //printf("achou \"%s\"\n", pal);
                        // sera um numero?
                        res = sscanf(pal, mascara, &numero);
                        if (res == 1) printf("%d ", numero);
                        free(pal);
                        if (*p == 0)
                        {
                            printf("]\n"); // termina a linha
                            return;
                        }
                        fase = 0;
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                };
                p += 1;
                break;

        };  // switch()
    };      // while()
    return;
}
```

#### saída do exemplo

```
==>     Linha 1: "-5 -4 -3 -2 -1"
        Extraidos: [ -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 ]
==>     Linha 2: "4 3 2 1"
        Extraidos: [ 4 3 2 1 ]
==>     Linha 3: "3 2 1"
        Extraidos: [ 3 2 1 ]
==>     Linha 4: "2 1"
        Extraidos: [ 2 1 ]
==>     Linha 5: "                   1"
        Extraidos: [ 1 ]
==>     Linha 6: ""
        Extraidos: [ ]
```

E pode adaptar para o que precisa. Um caminho comum é usar

```
    int** processa_linha(char*);
```

E retornar um vetor de `int*` terminado por `NULL`. Assim pode chamar a função e ela retorna os valores arrumadinhos para você processar.

Outro seria criar algo como

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned N; // quantos
    int*     valor;

}   Valores;

Valores* processa_linha(char*);
```

Para retornar um vetor de `int` e o total de números na linha

Se precisar de um exemplo disso e não encontrar avise e eu escrevo um e adiciono aqui

### `sscanf()` vc `fscanf()`

Se os dados estiverem em um arquivo `fscanf()` não tem o problema de avançar o ponteiro da string, já que o arquivo é, claro, `FILE*` um ponteiro.

Então é mais simples consumir os dados.

Mas para não perder a noção de linha é preciso usar um delimitador, e não pode ser espaço nem `TAB`. Como eu disse, essas funções foram escritas com arquivos tipo csv em mente. O delimitador pode ser `'\n'` mas não seria muito útil ;)

Se usar uma vírgula, o clássico, veja esse programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE* in = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
    if (in == NULL) return -1;
    const char* mask = "%30[^,\n]%c"; // virgula
    char        delim;
    int         linha  = 1;
    int         numero = 0;
    int         res    = 0;
    char        campo[30];
    printf("linha %d: [ ", linha);
    while (1)
    {
        res = fscanf(in, mask, campo, &delim);
        switch (res)
        {
            case -1: // tanto faz se deu erro
            case 0: 
                printf("]\n\n");
                return 0;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (sscanf(campo, "%d", &numero) == 1)
                    printf("%d ", numero);
                break;
            case 2:
            default:  // so pode ser 2
                if (delim == '\n')
                {
                    linha += 1;
                    if (sscanf(campo, "%d", &numero) == 1)
                        printf("%d ]\nlinha %d: [ ", numero, linha);
                }
                else if (sscanf(campo, "%d", &numero) == 1)
                    printf("%d ", numero);
                break;
        }
    };  // while()
    return 0;
}
```

que lê esse arquivo

```
 -5, -4, x3x, -3, -2, -1
 4, 3, 2, 1
 3,2,1
 2,1
 1
x
```

E mostra

```
linha 1: [ -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 ]
linha 2: [ 4 3 2 1 ]
linha 3: [ 3 2 1 ]
linha 4: [ 2 1 ]
linha 5: [ 1 ]
linha 6: [ ]
```

Sim, é muito chato :D